# The solutions of $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{x}+\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{x}+\sqrt{2}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{6}\right)^{x}=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

There is an algorithm to solve this equation? $$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{x}+ \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{x}+\sqrt{2} \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{6}\right)^{x}=1$$

I can see that one solution is $x=1$ but I'm wondering if there're other solutions. Some hints?

Comment: The function in the left hand side is decreasing, so admits single solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello There is only one solution because left side of equation is decreasing function , right side is constant. Intersection of decreasing and constant functions have only one point. That point is (x,y)=(1,1)

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

The left side is the sum of three exponential functions, all of which are decreasing.  So the left side always decreases.  Its graph can cross the line $y=1$ at only one point.

Comment: Thank you for your help!